# How to get a certain value from an array of objects in python

Tags: python-3.x

ok so this is my program so far to operate as an ordering system of a cafe with multiple items. My goal is to calculate the price of an order, store that order to keep count of which coffee was ordered and how many of that coffee was ordered. Right now I am stuck on calculating the order total for an order. The main problem im stuck on is getting the coffee price of a coffee based on what the user wants, say if i want x coffee, i need to get the price of that coffee. I've stored instances of coffee in an array and right now I am not sure of how to get the price of a coffee to be used in the calculation of the total price

class Coffee(object):

```
def __init__ (self, coffee_type, price):
    self.coffee_type = coffee_type
    self.price = price
```

class Order(object):

```
def __init__(self, coffee_type, coffee_amount):
    self.coffee_type = coffee_type
    self.coffee_amount = coffee_amount
```

if **name** =="**main**":

```
coffee_available=[Coffee("1 : Flat White", 3.50), 
                  Coffee("2 : Long Black", 3.50), 
                  Coffee("3 : Cappuccino", 4.00), 
                  Coffee("4 : Espresso", 3.25), 
                  Coffee("5 : Latte", 3.50)]

ordering = 'Y'
total_cost = 0

while ordering == 'Y':

    print("Coffee Type\t\tPrice")
    print("-----------\t\t-----")
    for coffee in coffee_available:
        print("{}\t- - -\t$ {}".format(coffee.coffee_type,coffee.price))
    print()
    order_coffee = int(input("What is the number of the coffee you want? "))

    order_amount = input("How many would you like to order? ")

    new_order = None

    if order_coffee >= 1 and order_coffee <=5:
        coffee_choice = coffee_available[coffee.price]
        new_order = Order(coffee_choice, order_amount)
        total_cost = new_order.coffee_type * order_amount

    else:
        print ("Please enter a valid number")

    dine_in = input('You like to dine in? (Y/N)')
    dine_in = dine_in.upper()

    if dine_in == 'Y' or 'YES':
        total_cost = total_cost + (total_cost * 0.1)
        print (total_cost)
        Ordering = 'N'

    elif dine_in == 'N' or 'No':
        total_cost = total_cost             
    else:
        print("Please enter a valid input")
        continue
```

Comment: it will be more helpful if you post all the `Coffee` and `Order` classes in your post. What about `dine_in` class, you didn't post anything about it??

Answer (score 0):

It's better to split the id of the coffee from the name:

```
class Coffee(object):
    def __init__ (self, coffee_id, coffee_type, price):
        self.coffee_id = coffee_id
        self.coffee_type = coffee_type
        self.price = price
```

Then when you create object use:

```
Coffee(1, "Flat White", 3.5)
```

And when you want the price use:

```
def get_price(coffee_available, coffee_id):
    for coffee in coffee_available:
        if coffee.coffee_id == coffee_id:
            return coffee.price
    return None
```

Comment: that function was what I was looking for, thank you very much. Unfortunately it has come up with a TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float' error. I will try to resolve this problem but any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: @killerstick1This is unrelated error. In this line:
         total_cost = new_order.coffee_type * order_amount, 
you multiply string with float, perhaps thats the problem.